# Background HTML visibiltiy in Silverlight Full Screen Mode

Tags: silverlight

I am creating a page with Silverlight component and some HTML controls.

On enabling Silverlight's full screen, I am unable to view the background HTML controls. Even if I set the xaml's background to transparent.

Please let me know if it's possible to view the HTML controls in full screen mode of Silverlight or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that such thing is possible, for security reasons, as the keybordsupport in Fullscreen is. It would enable you create such things as a app totally visible observing the movements.
But I might be wrong !

Answer (score 0):

Fullscreen mode takes the content currently restricted to rectangle on hosts window (the Browser client area window) and displays it on full screen window.  This full screen window is a new window and contains only the Siverlight content.

When silverlight is rendering in a windowless mode it is simply rendering directly on to the host window.  When you got fullscreen mode in Silverlight you are not affecting the hosts window, fullscreen effectively suppends windowless mode as it needs a new window of its own to render on.